# How to identify more than 500 features from closest facility analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, network-analyst

I am new to and using ArcGIS Desktop 10

I have done the closest facility analyst.
And there are many routes laying on my network.
I want to know how many routes use the road section(one feature in network layer), and so on for all of the network.
When I use identify, it can just return at most 500 features.

**How can I get more?**
I've google for this, I know I have to edit the "maxcount" but I can't find that!

Answer (score 9):

In ArcGIS 10, the default number of features returned by an ArcGIS Service for queries (identify/find/query) is 1000, though yours could have been set to 500.  You will need to change the service properties in order to increase the maximum number of results.  You can do that by stopping the map service, going to Service Properties - Parameters tab, and setting the Maximum Number of Records Returned by Server to a suitable value.  Be sensible about the value though - your browser will not appreciate having 10,000 records returned along with their geometries.

Alternately you can configure the maximum number of records by changing the map service config file directly and restarting the service.  The config file can be found in Program Files\ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\user\cfg and will be named ServiceName.MapServer.cfg.  You will want to update the MaxRecordCount node.

---

Comment: user3824 posted this in the answer (but is a comment) thanks a lot !!
but I can't find the ServiceName.MapServer.cfg.
I can find only: Program Files\ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\user\cfg\FolderInfo
What's wrong with my server?!
I'll try the first solution, but I meet another problem...
I don't know how to add users to the agsadmin and agsusers groups.....
and where can I find the Service properties?